# How to edit manifest when specifying multiple sources for one task with AWS Sagemaker ground truth

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, crowdsourcing

I would like to create a task to have one worker perform labeling of multiple sound sources with AWS Sagemaker ground truth.
I created a manifest file as follows, but I cannot specify multiple sound sources with source-ref.
How to create a manifest file?

dataset.manifest

```
 {"source-ref":["s3://sagemaker-sample/audio_01.wav", "s3://sagemaker-sample/audio_02.wav"]}
```

Error

> ClientError: Manifest: s3://sagemaker-sample/dataset.manifest has
>   invalid format at line number 0. Make sure that source or source-ref
>   field contains a string value

Comment: Your format is different than that in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html)?

Comment: Thanks!
However, the following message is displayed.  

[Error Message]  
**ClientError: Manifest: s3://sagemaker-sample/dataset_multi.manifest has invalid format at line number 0. Make sure that the record contains either 'source' or 'source-ref' but not both.**

[Manifest File]
`{"sources":[{"source-ref":"s3://sagemaker-sample/signal_01.wav", "name":"signal_01.wav"}, {"source-ref":"s3://sagemaker-sample/signal_02.wav", "name":"signal_02.wav"}]}`

Answer (score 1):

Specifying multiple sources as a list under a single "source-ref" is not supported. For the actual format, please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-input-data-input-manifest.html. Each line represents a reference to a single S3 file as show below.
Example:

```
{"source-ref": "S3 bucket location 1"}
{"source-ref": "S3 bucket location 2"}
   ...
{"source-ref": "S3 bucket location n"}
```

For your case, it would be

```
{"source-ref": "s3://sagemaker-sample/audio_01.wav"}
{"source-ref": "s3://sagemaker-sample/audio_02.wav"}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation instead of just posting a link.